# Reading a csv file and adding newline character at different positons in scala

Tags: scala

here is my dataset :

```
UNIT_TYPE,ALARM_TYPE,ALARM_INFO,LOCATION,RAISED_TIME,ALARM_GROUP,PROBABLE_CAUSE,"ECP,OPTIC_TRANSCEIVER_RX_LOS,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]-ECP[0]/CPRI_PORT[10],2017-08-31,14:30:48,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,LINE_INTERFACE_FAILURE,major,3116378,When,optic,cable,open,or,optical,signal,strength,decreases.,4",
```

**Reqired pattern:**

```
UNIT_TYPE,ALARM_TYPE,ALARM_INFO,LOCATION,RAISED_TIME,ALARM_GROUP,PROBABLE_CAUSE,(\n)
    "ECP,OPTIC_TRANSCEIVER_RX_LOS,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]-ECP[0]/CPRI_PORT[10],2017-08-31,14:30:48,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,LINE_INTERFACE_FAILURE,major,3116378,When,optic,cable,open,or,optical,signal,strength,decreases.,4",(\n)
```

This dataset is a comma-separated one but the problem is it is all coming in a single string, the result should be in different rows and in my case it is all coming in a single row instead of different rows so that I can relate it into an excel sheet.

I need to add a new line character (\n) after PROBABE_CUASE and then again newline character after 4".
I am actually creating a CSV file, but unable to add **/n** to separate my line 
can someone help

Comment: Please edit the question to 1. make it more readable 2. show the code you are currently using to solve your problem

Comment: jrook Hope now you can help me

Comment: From what you have given in the question, it seems that rows are separated by `"` and columns are separated by `,`. If that is the case you can use `split()` to get what you want

Comment: yes i used that approach only , but unable to use " as a pattern to split . 
You got it right now , rows can be separated by " as delimiiter but unable to pass " into split method 
//val res2 = lines1.split(" " ") ---> soemthing like this gives an erro

Comment: Maybe also add the format requirements to the question?

Comment: cant we pass " as a delimiter into split , this will make my work very easy . 

can you just give me a sample code on how this can be done ?

Comment: @Learner  now you have any idea ??

Comment: Take a look at my answer. We can pass a delimiter into split too. `str.split(",")` for example, splits the string by commas.

Comment: @jrook yes we can pass comma as a delimiter but to pass " in delimiter its highly impossible

Comment: Take a look at my answer. It is possible. Just use `"""` instead of `"` for defining inputs to the `split` function.

Comment: @jrook  , hey bro got the solution finally

Answer (score -1):

#

To resolve the question , i replaced the identifier to & and then gave a new line character . 
#

## #

my code :

```
package learningscala
import scala.io.Source
import scala.xml.XML
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import java.io.{File, FileOutputStream}

object hello {
  def main(args: Array[String] ) {

    val fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/aditya/Downloads/file.txt"))
Console.withOut(fos) {

   println("UNIT_TYPE,ALARM_TYPE,ALARM_INFO,LOCATION,RAISED_TIME,ALARM_GROUP,PROBABLE_CAUSE \t\n")

  // bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/home/aditya/Downloads/sample.csv")
    //for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines) {
       //prints the specific line 
      //println(line)

        // do whatever you want with the columns here
      val lines = Source.fromFile("/home/aditya/Downloads/sample.csv")
      //println(lines)
      val regex = new Regex("EQUIPMENT_ALARM")

       for (line <- lines.getLines())
       { 
                                           regex.findFirstIn(line) match {
                                        case Some(text) => println( line + "")
                                          //case Some(text) => println() 
                                          case None => println()

                                             }
       }

  val file = Source.fromFile("/home/aditya/Downloads/file.txt").getLines().filter(!_.isEmpty()).mkString(" &# ")
     printf(file)
    //var str = "Hello123"
val res = file.split("#")



 val fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/aditya/Downloads/file1.txt"))


Console.withOut(fos) {

val res1 = println(res.deep.mkString("\n"))

  val lines1 = Source.fromFile("//home/aditya/Downloads/file1.txt").mkString
printf(lines1)
val res2 = lines1.split("\\s+")


val fos =   new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/aditya/Downloads/file2.csv"))

 Console.withOut(fos) { 

val res3 = println(res2.deep.mkString(","))
//val nameValuePairs = result.split("&")

 val lines2 = Source.fromFile("/home/aditya/Downloads/file2.csv").mkString
 //printf(lines2)
val res4 = lines2.split(",&,")



val fos =   new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/aditya/Downloads/file3.csv"))
Console.withOut(fos) {



val res5 = println(res4.deep.mkString("\n"))
val lines3 = Source.fromFile("/home/aditya/Downloads/file3.csv").mkString
val res6 = lines3.replace("\"", "")
val fos =   new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/aditya/Downloads/file3.csv"))
Console.withOut(fos) {


printf(res6)
}
}

  //val regex = new Regex("  ECP,  ")






//val res2 = lines1.split("\n").map(_.split("\\s+")(0)).mkString(", ")
//printf(res2)
//val res2 = lines1.split("\\s+")

    // val res2 = file.split("\\s+")

    // val res3 = println(res2.deep.mkString(","))
     //printf("$res3")
 //val test = "/home/aditya/Downloads/file.txt".split ("\\s+").map (_.trim).mkString ("\n")
     //val res2 = res.split("\\W")
 //val res3 = println()
    // val res2 = file.split("\\s+")
}

  }
    }
  }

}
```

### #

#### #

So , what i have done is , i created an extra identifier & which helped me to apply the split operation sucessfully .

#### #

#

Output

UNIT_TYPE,ALARM_TYPE,ALARM_INFO,LOCATION,RAISED_TIME,ALARM_GROUP,PROBABLE_CAUSE

ECP,OPTIC_TRANSCEIVER_RX_LOS,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]-ECP[0]/CPRI_PORT[10],31-08-2017,14:30:48,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,LINE_INTERFACE_FAILURE,major,3116378,When,optic,cable,open,or,optical,signal,strength,decreases.,4,,,
ECP,OPTIC_TRANSCEIVER_TX_FAULT,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[1]-ECP[0]/CPRI_PORT[10],31-08-2017,14:30:48,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,LINE_INTERFACE_FAILURE,major,3116379,When,power,monitoring,result,of,laser,diode,is,abnormal.,6,,,
ECP,OPTIC_TRANSCEIVER_RX_LOS,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[2]-ECP[1]/CPRI_PORT[10],31-08-2017,14:30:48,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,LINE_INTERFACE_FAILURE,major,3116378,When,optic,cable,open,or,optical,signal,strength,decreases.,8,,,
ECP,OPTIC_TRANSCEIVER_TX_FAULT,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[2]-ECP[1]/CPRI_PORT[10],31-08-2017,14:30:48,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,LINE_INTERFACE_FAILURE,major,3116379,When,power,monitoring,result,of,laser,diode,is,abnormal.,10,,,
ECP,BOARD_DELETION,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[3]-ECP[2],31-08-2017,14:30:25,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,EQUIPMENT_MALFUNCTION,critical,3116366,When,the,board,is,dismounted.,2,,,,,,,
RRH,VSWR_FAIL,RRH[0_6_0]-RRH[0_6_0]/PATH[5],11-09-2017,01:26:23,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,TRANSCEIVER_PROBLEM,major,3149392,When,return,loss,of,ANT,port,is,below,the,threshold,level.,200,
SYS,COMMUNICATION_FAIL,RACK[0]/SHELF[0]/SLOT[6]-EAIU,31-08-2017,14:31:22,EQUIPMENT_ALARM,LINK_FAILURE,critical,3199381,When,the,Keep-Alive,message,response,cannot,be,received,between,DU,and,EAIU.,12

#

Comment: In the question posting, you said the string you are trying to parse is one big string (no new lines). But in your solution now you are using `getLines()` implying that the lines in your file are in fact separated. You should really try and clearly express the constraints and requirements of your problem. Also please edit this. It is virtually unreadable.

Comment: @jrook Hi i just added a snippet in the query , the question is apt . Actually i posted the whole code , instead i should have added the relevant code

Comment: @jrook I think you should put your ego aside and accept that i got a simpler soltuion , I just added an extra identifier apart from " , so that can be easily passed into split function . 
Anyways closing this thread , thanks for your help

Comment: *... and in my case it is all coming in a single row instead of different rows*. If this is really the case then using `getLines()` will not help you. You either did not explain your problem correctly or don't know what you are doing. Besides, the code you have pasted is not indented. The output is not formatted. I don't know what SO's policy is in such cases. But this question (and its answer) have to be marked in some way so others will not waste their time and hurt their eyes by viewing it.